# foreach loop not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
   if($c_type=='Telephone_Counseling')
        {
            $qry="SELECT eemp_id,email FROM book_tele_counseling_mstr WHERE CaseId='" . $cid . "'";
    $query=$this->db->query($qry);
           // return $query->result();

           foreach($query->result() as $row)
            {
               $eemp_id=$row->eemp_id;
               $email=$row->email;
            }

             $this->email->initialize($this->config);
        $message_str = 'Your session is closed';
        $this->email->from('no.reply@santulan.co.in', 'Santulan Suport Team');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject("This is mail from counselor");
        $this->email->message($message_str);
        $this->email->send();


          }
```

In the above code i am supposed to get the result from the above query but the debugger is not going in to the foreach loop while i am debugging the code

Comment: Check whether your query is fetching multiple records.

Comment: no only to single recipient whose case id in the table

Comment: is $cid filled?, what does $query->num_rows() return, I would say 0, therefore no results to fetch trough

Comment: yes Xavjer num_rows returns 0 ....whats the problem is the query please help me

Comment: Don't just change the question with another one. Post a new question instead ... and please, make at least a little effort to debug it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong syntax of `$query->result`

```
foreach($query->result as $row)
```

It would be

```
foreach($query->result() as $row)
```

Read [$query->result()](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Comment: please somebody help me with this

Comment: in the query i am not getting any result  and . $cid is string ,when i use num_rows() it shows 0 as result

Comment: What is the value of `$cid` and try to print your query and run in phpmyadmin

Comment: its value is TC-76 when i run my query in phpmyadmin it runs fine too

Comment: hello whats the problem in the query

Comment: try with `$row = $query->row();

if (isset($row))
{
        echo $row->eemp_id;
        echo $row->email;
        
}`

Comment: what is the datatype of field in database for `CaseId`

Comment: its data type is string

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access `$query->result` (a property that doesn't exist) instead of `$query->result()` (a method).

Comment: what should i have to write there $query->result()   is it wrong or right please tell me

Comment: "SELECT email FROM end_employee_master WHERE customer_id =(SELECT eemp_id FROM book_e_counseling_mst WHERE  CaseId like 'EC-" .  $cid . "'  )"

Comment: i am not getting the result here in the query please tell me whats the problem here in query